# Elixir function brackets

Tags: elixir

Hi I'am learning elixir atm (just started) and i never used to do functional programming, so my question is what does brackets after function name do.
I am watching some internet course, and want to try to make some app for training but dont really understand.

```
   defmodule Cards do
  def create_deck do
    values = ["Ace","Two","Three", "Four", "Five"]
    suits = ["Spades", "Clubs", "Hearts", "Diamonds"]

    for suit <- suits, value <- values do
      "#{value} of #{suit}"
    end
  end

  def shuffle(deck) do
    Enum.shuffle(deck)
  end

  def contains**(deck, card) do
    Enum.member?(deck, card)
  end

  def deal(deck, hand_size) do
    Enum.split(deck, hand_size)
  end
    def save(deck, filename) do
    binary = :erlang.term_to_binary(deck)
    File.write(filename, binary)
  end

    def load(filename) do
      {status, binary} = File.read(filename)
      :erlang.binary_to_term(binary)
    end
end
```

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "brackets"?  Do you mean `(` `)` or `[` `]`?  Are you getting some sort of error message when you attempt to compile the code?  If so please post the message.

Comment: ( ) i dont have any error i just want to know what they are for.

Comment: in line def shuffle(deck)

Comment: what that (deck) is for

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `(deck)` is a way of specifying the argument to the function.  `deck` is the argument passed to the `shuffle` function. You can find a bit more about the function syntax [here](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/modules-and-functions.html).